# How to access a string from another method

Tags: string, class, methods, scope

How would I access the string filename from a different method?

```
    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        filename = Server.MapPath("images/") + e.FileName.ToString();
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(filename);     
    }
```

I have tried declaring filename in the scope of the class like this:

```
private string filename = String.Empty;
```

But when trying to access from another method like this:

```
public void GetFilename() 
{
lblResults.Text = filename;
}
```

The string is empty. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the order you call your methods, if your call `GetFilename()` before `AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(...)` has been called at least once. Your `filename` member will be empty, because you initialise it empty.

As you are dealing with asynchronous, you should make sure to wait for filename to be set by your function.